# How to loop through a list of strings to use them in a condition?

Tags: python

```
source = open("file1")    
out = open("file2", "w")

days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

for line in source:
    out.write(line)
    if line.startswith('HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE DAYS TO BE LOOPED'):
        break    
out.close()
```

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you want. What do you mean by "... I would like the days to be looped". Please add some explanation about what you want, and how what you tried does not work. Simply pasting code isn't enough -  we are not psychic.

Comment: Apologies. I want it to check if the line starts with either 'Mon' or 'Tue' or 'Wed' etc. If the line does start with any of these, then break the loop. I tried using the OR operator but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: What about a line that starts with Month or Wedding or Thuringia or Fright or Satisfactory or Sunset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `help(str.startswith)`, you can see that the method accepts a tuple of strings to search for, so you can do it all in one step:

```
>>> 'Mon is the first day'.startswith(('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'))
True
```

Here is a variant that runs on older versions of Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
>>> pattern = '|'.join(days)
>>> if re.match(pattern, 'Tue is the first day'):
        print 'Found'

Found
```

Comment: TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: @AshleyJohnKent: Either you are using a Python version older than 2.5, or you passed in a list instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

Since all your strings are the same length, you could do this:

```
if line[:3] in days:
    break
```

If that's too much of an assumption:

```
if any(line.startswith(day) for day in days):
    break
```

Another tip (assuming you're on Python 2.7 or 3.2:

```
with open("file1") as source, open("file2", "w") as out:
    for line in source:
        out.write(line)
        if any(line.startswith(day) for day in days):
            break
```

and you don't have to think about closing your files manually, even if an exception occurs.

And if you're still on Python 2.4 or lower (why??) just build your own [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I get this particular error: NameError: name 'any' is not defined. Something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a 5-year-old version of Python? `any()` was added in Python 2.5, back in 2006.

Answer (score 3):

```
if line.startswith(tuple(days)):
```

from the documentation:

```
S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

Return True if S starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

The last line is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
if line[:3] in days:
    # True
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#Hackish, but works
if min([line.find(x) for x in days]) == 0:
```

Comment: That looks wrong.  str.find() returns negative one if the string is not found.  You would want ``if max(line.find(d) for d in days) >= 0: ...``.